# Can an ASP.Net 3.5 site run on a server with ASP.Net 4.0 on it?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

Can an ASP.Net 3.5 site run on a server with ASP.Net 4.0 on it?

On the server it has the 4.0 ASP.Net framework installed on it but the site I am making is for 3.5.  Do i need to have 3.5 framework installed too to make the page work?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, but in all likelihood, the 3.5 framework should already be installed. If not, ensure that it gets installed.

However, it's usually best to install the versions in order... I have had issues in the past when 4.0 was installed first and a "lesser" version afterward, or when 2.0 was installed before 1.1.  It's just good practice to install them in the correct order.

Comment: Yep.  I forgot about that. And I just dealt with that misconfiguration yesterday...  I think my memory is going as I age.

Answer (score 0):

All .net framework installers include the previous version including the service packs.. well they do if you download them directly from microsoft's website which ensures its the newest version.

I've never installed multiple version (1.1, then 2.0, then 3.0 and soforth).. always just the newest and I've never encountered a problem. However if you do get issues that approach might be helpful.